# why python if while ends in a dead loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

```
order = 2
selected = 0
while selected < 21: # because I can only select 20 rows the most once.
    current_tr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/ html / body / table / tbody / tr / td / div / div[3] / table / tbody / tr[%d]' % order) # form line 1. below the table's header
    if current_tr.get_attribute("bgcolor") is None: # no bgcolor means not yet reviewed
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[2]/div/a").click() # check the onclick content
        div_content = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[2]/div/div").text # fetch onclick content
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[2]/div/div/a").click()  # close the onclick content
        print(div_content)
        if "car" in div_content: #judge if certain string exists in onclick content
            list_content = div_content.split("【car】")
            car_close = list_content[1].strip() # fetch the content
            list_car = car_close.split(" ")
            car = list_doi[0]
            print(car)
            orderminus = order - 1
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('// *[ @ id = "%d"] / td[6] / a' % orderminus).click()  # pick this row,
            time.sleep(1)
            selected = selected + 1
            order = order + 0  #if this row is picked, the row will disappear, so the order won't change
        else:  ###problem is here, the else branch seems like never been executed ? otherwise the if always stands? no, not possible. there are ones exclude "car", the problem occurs at the first instance of div_content without "car"
            order = order + 1 # if "car" is not in
            time.sleep(1)
     else: # if already reviewed, order + 1
         order = order + 1
```

above is my code using selenium to navigate the webpage with a table.
First judgement: if the current row is reviewed,
not yet reviewed? ok, print the info;
already reviewed？skip it.

then plus judgement: if there certain string "car" in the info:
no? skip;
yes, click it, the row disappear;

But currently when I am running this, the actual status is :
when doing the plus judement, if the string "car" is not in the info,
it keeps printing the info, it seems it not doing the else branch, is doing the line 6_9 in this snippet, always, dead end loop.

Why? anybody give me a clue?

to make things clear， i have simplified my code as below:

```
list = []
list.append("ff122")
list.append("carff")
list.append("ff3232")
list.append("ffcar")
list.append("3232")


order = 0
selected = 0
while selected < 6:
    current_tr = list[order]
    print("round %d %s" % (order, current_tr))
    if "ff" in current_tr:
        print("ff is in current_tr")
        if "car" in current_tr:
             print("car")
             selected = selected + 1
             order = order + 0
        else:
            order = order + 1
            print("order is %d" % order)
    else: # if already reviewed, order + 1
        order = order + 1
        print("order is %d" % order)
```

everybody can run this, what I need to do is firstly filter the "ff", if "ff" exists, then filter "car". both two conditions TRUE, selected +1, until selected reach certain number. in real instance, don't doubt that the list is long enough.

Comment: i guess there are not enough 21 `"car" in div_content` to finish the loop

Comment: Yes, you also need to check whether you've reached the last `div_content`, and if so exit the loop. You can probably do this with a for loop over the `div_content` elements, instead of a while loop.

Comment: better use `all_tr = find_elements_by_xpath` with char `s` in name `elements` to get all `tr` in table and later use `for`-loop with `all_tr[:21]`

Comment: @datdinhquoc definitely enough. Because the repeat is occuring at line 6-9.  so i know that. the problem is when "car" is not in the div_content.

Comment: while is because there is the amount limit: 20 tasks I can pick the most. problem here is when the first div_content dont have "car". it repeatly do the line 6-9. seems like the order never change. So the else branch "doi not in div_content" haven't been executed ever.

Comment: @furas  hello, because it's dynamic, once the row I picked, the row will delimited from the table, and new one will automatically been added into the table(first page, 20 rows.)

Comment: you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in values. It is called `"print debuging"` and it may help to see problem. We can't run code. we can't even see this page, and we can't read in your mind - so you will have to test it on your own.

Comment: @furas  problems is clear. and you can see that there is a lot of print. I know what is print debugging.

Comment: I see only two `print()` - so it is not enough for debuging. maybe problem is clear for you but we can't run code to see  how it works.

Comment: @furas ok, you enlighted me, I've summarize my code, I create a little snippet to elaborate my puzzle. you can see that, and you can run that, it keep printing "round 1 carff
ff is in current_tr
car"  6 times,  which mean the internal else branch have not been executed ever. I wish if you can dive into my code to enlighten me further.